# Which Android intent to use to get the 'Save to device' behaviour in dropbox app?

Tags: android, android-intent

Currently I am able to implement store and retrieve file from Google Drive without issue but I want to add an additional functionality which is to save the file directly to local storage.

In dropbox app, if you try to export a file and in the chooser select 'Save to device', it will show something like below:

[image]

At first I thought they created the activity themselves but it looks very similar to the ACTION_GET_CONTENT intent that I am using.. 
My code is just something like:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 intent.setType("application/*");
 startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

which show something like below:

[image]

That makes me think that Dropbox app must be using an Android intent to save file to local storage like ACTION_ADD_CONTENT or something.. Or am I wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: that looks like the  Storage Access Framework: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html

Comment: This tutorial gives a detailed guide on how to do it, without needing to add storage access permissions (`READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`) to your app: https://jayrambhia.com/blog/android-fileprovider-ecosystem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Kuffs has it right — you are seeing the UI for the Storage Access Framework. Specifically, for a "save as" sort of feature, use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`. You will get back a `content:` `Uri` for the location that the user chose, and you can use a `ContentResolver` and `openOutputStream()` to write your data to that location.

Comment: Thanks again @CommonsWare! I read your answer in another thread on how to use FileProvider to create content: Uri to allow other apps to access my cache folder data and manage to get it working! I am still waiting for the update in your StreamProvider to be able to read database files directly too :)

Comment: @Bruce: "I am still waiting for the update in your StreamProvider to be able to read database files directly too" -- that shipped with 0.4.0 a week or so ago. `StreamProvider` does not support `getDatabasePath()` out of the box, but you can easily create a subclass to do it. I have a test case demonstrating it, and I have [documentation specifically discussing that scenario](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider/blob/master/docs/EXTENDING.markdown#supporting-other-stream-locations).

Comment: That is great news, I'll check it out!

Comment: @Bruce: BTW, back on the Storage Access Framework, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Documents/TinyTextEditor) implements a tabbed/multi-window text editor, using the Storage Access Framework. It demonstrates how to use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` for a "save as" scenario. Note that this project may be difficult to import and run right now, given that it relies on the N Developer Preview and some tricks to get N-aware apps to run on older devices. That'll clear up once the final Android N ships later this year.

Comment: With your answer above I actually got it working already and am now testing it XD. Just wondering how it runs on devices with API lower than 19 though

Comment: @Bruce: Well, my sample app doesn't -- it has `minSdkVersion` set to 19. `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` won't work on older devices. And, while `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` can be a semi-replacement for `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, I do not know of a legacy action that would work as an `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` replacement.

Comment: That's what I thought, guess I have no choice but to do manual write to disk in API < 19 with the downside of the extra write_external_storage permission.

Comment: @Bruce: Yes, though if you're not going to offer that option on 19+ devices, you can use `maxSdkVersion` on the `<uses-permission>` to not ask for that permission on those newer devices.

Comment: Have you tried writing data to Google Drive using Storage Access Framework? The file always ends up with 0 bytes. I must be missing something. I thought it will work on the shelf since Google Drive is the only option available besides local storage when I call startActivityForResult using ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT

Comment: @Bruce: No, because I don't use Google Drive. Make sure you `flush()` your `OutputStream`.